# Why plotly python doesn’t draw vertical surfaces?

Tags: python, plotly, vertical-alignment, plotly-python, surface

Using the below code, simply I can draw a surface that I need.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

u = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 24)
v = np.linspace(-1, 0, 8)

u,v = np.meshgrid(u,v)

u = u.flatten()
v = v.flatten()

z = np.sin(u/2)#*0+1 


points2D = np.vstack([u,v]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)
simplices = tri.simplices

fig = ff.create_trisurf(x=u, y=v, z=z,
                         colormap="Portland",
                         simplices=simplices,
                         title="Mobius Band")
fig.show()
```

and the result is correct as I need:

Results
[image]

But when I make the surface horizontal, I encounter with error?

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

u = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 24)
v = np.linspace(-1, 0, 8)

u,v = np.meshgrid(u,v)

u = u.flatten()
v = v.flatten()

z = np.sin(u/2)*0+1 


points2D = np.vstack([u,v]).T
tri = Delaunay(points2D)
simplices = tri.simplices

fig = ff.create_trisurf(x=u, y=v, z=z,
                         colormap="Portland",
                         simplices=simplices,
                         title="Mobius Band")
fig.show()
```

What is the problem???

Comment: what is the error text?

Comment: Your title says "vertical" surface, but you really mean "horizontal", right?

Comment: Not really a trisurface if you have do depth is it? Perhaps check out https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi, You are right but I get same error for Vertical'

Comment: @ti7 Hi, this is the error text that I get:
Incorrect relation between vmin and vmax. The vmin value cannot be bigger than or equal to the value of vmax.

Comment: Dear @GrahamChapman , I'm checking the link that you sent and then I speak more. Thanks

Comment: Dear @GrahamChapman , I didn't understand your comment. would you explain more. What should I do if I want to draw a vertical surface???

Comment: Ah, so `figure_factory` explicitly prohibits plots that are horizontal planes or vertical planes.  You can work around that by finding your own min and max values and supplying them, instead of allowing it to find them.

Comment: Dear @TimRoberts , Thanks for the response. So I understood that there is no problem about my code. But what is their reason for this limitation!!!. If it is possible let me know what is your suggestion for drawing vertical surfaces using plotly?

Comment: They just prohibit figures where an axis has 0 size.  That's reasonable.  You can use `fig.update_xaxes(range=...)` and `fig.update_yaxes(range=...)` to set your own limits.